# Finding start time and end time in a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a data set that has employees clocking in and out. It looks like this (note two entries per employee):

```
Employee    Date   Time
Emp1       1/1/16  06:00
Emp1       1/1/16  13:00
Emp2       1/1/16  09:00
Emp2       1/1/16  17:00
Emp3       1/1/16  11:00
Emp3       1/1/16  18:00
```

I want to get the data to look like this:

```
Employee   Date   Start   End
Emp1       1/1/16 06:00   13:00
Emp2       1/1/16 09:00   17:00
Emp3       1/1/16 11:00   18:00
```

I would like to get it into a data frame format so that I can do some calculations.

I currently have tried

```
df['start'] = np.where((df['employee']==df['employee']&df['date']==df['date']),df['time'].min())
```

I also tried:

```
df.groupby(['employee','date]['time'].max()
```

How do I get two columns out of one?

Comment: I would recommend to merge `Date` and `Time` into one column as `DateTime`. That would greatly simplify your work.

Comment: If I merged the date and time together, what would I do then?

Comment: Why not `df.groupby(['Employee', 'Date']).agg([min, max])`?

Comment: @JohnGalt see my answer below. I also think that's what needs to be done. But I believe first you need to convert the `Date` and `Time` columns to datetime objects. Looks like they are string now and `min` / `max` doesn't work as intended with string date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to merge Date and Time into one column as DateTime. That would greatly simplify your work. You can do something like this:

```
df['DateTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+" "+df['Time'])
df.groupby('Employee')['DateTime'].agg([min, max])
```

There are other options depending the content of your data. If you know that all the entries will be on the same day you can simply do:

```
# First convert Date and Time columns to DateTime type
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.time
df.groupby('Employee').agg([min, max])
```

no need to create a DateTime column in this case.

If you want to know Start End times per each day you can do:

```
# First convert Date and Time columns to DateTime type
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.time
df.groupby(['Employee','Date'])['Time'].agg([min, max])
```

Comment: I tried it at it worked! Thank you! Now, I want the 'employee' to show up in every row. I need to merge this data frame into another data frame.

Comment: Not exactly sure if that's what you are asking but try this: `grouped=df.groupby(['Employee','Date'])['Time'].agg([min, max])` then `grouped.reset_index()`

Comment: It did not work, but I will do some more research. I think it might just be a limitation on the groupby. If I cannot find anything, I will ask another question. Thank you again!

Comment: I found out that .reset_index does work. you have to do the following grouped=df.groupby(['Employee','Date'])['Time'].agg([min, max]).reset_index()  I tried assigning it based on the grouped and it did not work.