# How to get the start and end date period of a data sequence in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data:

```
0   0   2020-04-01 00:00:00 
1   1   2020-04-01 00:01:00
2   2   2020-04-01 00:02:00

41732   43195   2020-04-30 23:55:00
41733   43196   2020-04-30 23:56:00
41734   43197   2020-04-30 23:57:00
```

And I want to get the start time and the end time from a process per day/hour/min.
For example:

```
0   0   2020-04-01 00:00:00 #start time
2   2   2020-04-01 00:02:00 #end time
```

Comment: How the output should look like? Should the start and end be calculated per day?

Comment: please check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747795/finding-start-time-and-end-time-in-a-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print ('start:', df.date.min())
print ('end:', df.date.max())
```

Comment: The start and end should be calculated per day, not just min and max of entire dataset.

Comment: But if this repeat in different times?

Comment: What do you mean? please explain better